# Opening [ModalPopLite] Popup Window from clicking a HyperLinkField in a Gridview

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, modalpopup

I'm currently working on a website. I want to open a pop-up when I click on a hyperlinkfield in the gridview table I have.

```
<asp:GridView ID="EmployeeList" runat="server"/>

                    <Columns>
                        <asp:HyperLinkField
                            DataNavigateUrlFields="EmpID"
                            HeaderText="EMP ID"
                            Target="_blank"
                            DataNavigateUrlFormatString="google.com"
                            DataTextField="EmpID">
                        </asp:HyperLinkField>
                    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Here's my sample script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#newuser_pop').modalPopLite({ openButton: '#clicker1'});
    });
</script>
```

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your case is that in asp.net controls are server side so in order to get id in jquery do  as shown :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
     $('#<%= newuser_pop.ClientID %>').modalPopLite({ openButton: '#clicker1'});
  });
</script>
```

Comment: and what change should I make in my HyperLinkField then?